# Select only 1 'control number' without using distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT [CtrlNo]
,[RefNo]
,[DealNoCat]
,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
,[tBank].BankName
,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
,[DaysOut]
,[FundDate]
,[Comment]
FROM [tContractsInTransit]
INNER JOIN tFIManagers
ON tFIManagers.FIManagerID = tContractsInTransit.FIManagerID
INNER JOIN tBank
ON tBank.BankID = tContractsInTransit.BankID
INNER JOIN tCustomer
ON tCustomer.CustomerID = tContractsInTransit.CustomerID
WHERE PFX = 'x'
AND Paid = 'false'
GROUP BY [CtrlNo]
,[RefNo]
,[DealNoCat]
,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
,[tBank].BankName
,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
,[DaysOut]
,[FundDate]
,[Comment]
ORDER BY CtrlNo DESC
```

However, this doesn't give me the results that I want even though it's doing exactly what I tell it to do. If there are 10 records total, and three of the records have the same CtrlNo, it will display all three of these records if one of the other columns such as RefNo and DaysOut are not the same. I need to display the one record from those three that has the least amount of DaysOut. For example, if the DaysOut is 2, 6, and 48, the record with 2 should be display. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we have a SQLFiddle and visual representation of what you want as the output to be?

Comment: Use Min() on that column and remove it from group by or a window function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a recently new sqlserver you can use a window function like row_number() as in:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT [CtrlNo]
    ,[RefNo]
    ,[DealNoCat]
    ,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
    ,[tBank].BankName
    ,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
    ,[DaysOut]
    ,[FundDate]
    ,[Comment]
    , row_number() over (partition by CtrlNo order by DaysOut) as rn
    FROM [tContractsInTransit]
    INNER JOIN tFIManagers
        ON tFIManagers.FIManagerID = tContractsInTransit.FIManagerID
    INNER JOIN tBank
        ON tBank.BankID = tContractsInTransit.BankID
    INNER JOIN tCustomer
        ON tCustomer.CustomerID = tContractsInTransit.CustomerID
    WHERE PFX = 'x'
      AND Paid = 'false'
) as T
WHERE rn = 1;
ORDER BY CtrlNo DESC
```

Comment: Awesome solution. This will help greatly!

Answer (score 2):

You want to leave off the DISTINCT keyword and use Aggregate functions.  In this case, MIN.
Notice that 'DaysOut' is also removed from the GroupBy clause

```
SELECT [CtrlNo]
,[RefNo]
,[DealNoCat]
,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
,[tBank].BankName
,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
,MIN([DaysOut]) as Min_DaysOut
,[FundDate]
,[Comment]
FROM [tContractsInTransit]
INNER JOIN tFIManagers
ON tFIManagers.FIManagerID = tContractsInTransit.FIManagerID
INNER JOIN tBank
ON tBank.BankID = tContractsInTransit.BankID
INNER JOIN tCustomer
ON tCustomer.CustomerID = tContractsInTransit.CustomerID
WHERE PFX = 'x'
AND Paid = 'false'
GROUP BY [CtrlNo]
,[RefNo]
,[DealNoCat]
,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
,[tBank].BankName
,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
,[FundDate]
,[Comment]
ORDER BY CtrlNo DESC
```

Comment: This works well, if the RefNo are the same. But since they are different, records with same CtrlNo are still returned. But I will keep this in mind on other projects!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher version:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT [CtrlNo]
,[RefNo]
,[DealNoCat]
,[tCustomer].[CustomerName]
,[tBank].BankName
,[tFIManagers].[FIName]
,[DaysOut]
,[FundDate]
,[Comment]
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY CtrlNo, ORDER BY DaysOut ASC) AS rn
FROM [tContractsInTransit]
INNER JOIN tFIManagers
ON tFIManagers.FIManagerID = tContractsInTransit.FIManagerID
INNER JOIN tBank
ON tBank.BankID = tContractsInTransit.BankID
INNER JOIN tCustomer
ON tCustomer.CustomerID = tContractsInTransit.CustomerID
WHERE PFX = 'x'
AND Paid = 'false'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY CtrlNo DESC
```